# How can I get Macaulay2 to tell me if this ideal is prime?

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, computer-algebra-systems, macaulay2

I am trying to get Macaulay2 to confirm if $(y+zi,x^2 - z^2 - 1)$ is a prime ideal in $\Bbb{C}[x,y,z]$. Now as a small test, I tried to compute its radical by doing `R = CC[x,y,z]` and then setting `I = ideal (y+z*ii,x^2 - z^2 - 1)`. However when I put `radical I` and hit enter I get

> error: expected base field to be QQ or ZZ/p

Then I tried instead to set `R = RR[x]` and `I = (x^2 + 1)` and set `S = R/I[w,z,y]`. Then my ideal in the ring `S` should be `(y+z*x,w^2 - z^2 - 1)` but when I set `J = (y+z*x,w^2-z^2-1)` I get:

> error: expected pair to have a method for '*'

How can I get Macaulay2 to do this computation for me? I already know that my ideal is prime but I want to get Macaualay2 to do this computation. This is so that in future I can work over general base rings and not just $\Bbb{Q}$ or $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: And for those uninitiated [Maculay2](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Macaulay2/) is a software system for doing algebraic geometry computations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You usually get that error message when you're working in one ring and try to multiply elements in another ring. Try `use S`, and then `J = ideal (y+z*x,w^2-z^2-1)`.

This code worked for me:

```
R = QQ[x]
I = ideal(x^2+1)
S = R/I[w,z,y]
J = ideal(y+z*x,w^2-z^2-1)
isPrime J
>> true
```

Macaulay2 uses Gröbner bases to compute prime ideals and radicals. Because elements of $\mathbb{C}$ are represented as floating point numbers, the algorithms wont work over $\mathbb{C}$.

What you can do, is to do the computation over $\mathbb{Q}$, check that the generators is a Gröbner basis, and check that they (the generators of the ideal) remain irreducible after tensoring with $\mathbb{C}$, if so, <strike>then prime over $\mathbb{Q}$ should imply prime over $\mathbb{C}$.</strike>

*Added:* What I ment with the previous paragraph: tensoring with an algebraically closed field can sometimes destroy primeness (for example the ideal $(x^2+1) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}[x]$ is prime, but not after tensoring with $\mathbb{C}$).

However, after thinking about this, I don't know if it is possible to do this in M2 - you really would have to use some kind of tricks to prove primeness over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Dear Fredrik, thanks for your answer. I get that a Groebner basis for my ideal is $(y - zi,x^2 - z^2 - 1)$. I can probably tensor it with $\Bbb{C}$, but what do you mean "check if they remain irreducible after tensoring with $\Bbb{C}$"? I know that $y+zi$ and $x^2 -z^2 - 1$ are irreducible polynomials over $\Bbb{C}$.

Comment: @BenjaLim: I've tried to expand my answer in order to explain what I ment. However, after thinking about this, I don't know if there are any algorithms in M2 that can factor over algebraically closed fields.